# My table has no non key attribute and it is not showing in entity model or not creating its entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am developing an app in asp.net in Which I am using an entity model. My some table has no non key attributes, only have primary key attributes which are foreign key attributes in other tables. Entity model not creating entities of such table. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. Those tables are just helpers used to model many-to-many relationship in the database where such relations cannot be modeled directly. Because EF supports many-to-many relations it doesn't expose those tables as entities and instead express the relation directly.

Comment: But I want to use these table attributes then how can I use those attributes?

Comment: What attributes. Those tables have only a key - no real attributes. You can mimic the usage directly through navigation properties on your main entities connected through many-to-many relation.